# Using grepl with single and multiple patterns

Tags: r, mapply, grepl

I am comparing patterns in a list to a dataframe. In some cases the pattern may be in a concatenated string (as seen in LIST below). If any element whether it is in a concatenated string or single string is in the dataframe Compare, I would like a TRUE value.  I am aware of the issues with grep and patterns of > 1, but maybe there is another way. My code works great for single patterns, but shows FALSE if the pattern of interest isn't the first element in the concatenated string.

LIST

```
structure(list(L29 = 11, S14 = 3, S2 = 1, S7 = 2, S71 = c(4, 
8, 9, 10), S91 = c(6, 7)), .Names = c("L29", "S14", "S2", "S7", 
"S71", "S91"))
```

Compare

```
 structure(list(L29 = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), S14 = c(3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3), S2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), S7 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2), S71 = c(4, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16), S91 = c(6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7)), .Names = c("L29", 
"S14", "S2", "S7", "S71", "S91"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code:

```
output <- as.data.frame(mapply(grepl, LIST, Compare 
), MoreArgs = list(pattern = "^[[:alnum:]]$",
                   ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Desired output

LIST will cycle through Compare and for S71 the values would be TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE. LIST's S71 variable is a concatenated string of c(4,8,9,10) hence the TRUE values correspond to those rows in the Compare dataframe, but those values do not match 15 and 16 for rows 5 and 6 of Compare hence FALSE values. For S91 all of the values will be TRUE since the concatenated value of c(6,7) exists in LIST.

Comment: Why are you calling your list `DF`? Also, why are you using regex? Aren't these exact matches? Maybe just `mapply(function(x, y) any(x %in% y), DF, Compare)`?

Comment: Made the DF change. This is a clean sample, but in some cases it won't be. So, I used regex to ensure I get the match I want.

Comment: So maybe provide an example for not "clean" sample? Otherwise using regex makes absolutely no sense here

Comment: I think....if I remember, for example the number 1 will match 10 and I don't want it to.

Comment: This is **exactly** why you shouldn't use regex for exact matches

Comment: I can get rid of it np, but I don't think that fixes my problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show an example where my code doesn't solve your problem please?

Comment: Yes, it does. I didn't notice your 'any' function.  However, my true LIST is over 30,000 rows and could be more columns and the any function will summarize each logical vector to TRUE if a TRUE exists. I want all of my rows with only the values in each element summarized to TRUE if there are multiple  TRUE FALSE values in a cell, element. Can your solution work here?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Again, please provide a representative example of your data

Comment: What's your desired result? Also, it's a bit confusing to talk about rows when talking about lists; they have no natural rows.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I updated my sample data (Compare) with a description of my desired output. Hope this helps.

Comment: The part where you say "LIST's S71 variable is a concatenated string of c(4,8,9,10)" is confusing.  In the sample data you present, `LIST[["S71"]]` is a numeric vector, not a string or character vector.  If your data are like the sample data in the question, can't you loop through and use David's suggestion of `%in%`:  `lapply(names(COMPARE), function(ii) COMPARE[, ii] %in% LIST[[ii]])`?

Comment: @alistaire did my edits to the data make my question more clear

Comment: Still looks like `mapply(\`%in%\`, Compare, LIST)` to me. When I said show your desired result, I meant actually show what the resulting data.frame should look like for your sample data.